# select records based on date

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table Employees with timestamp field createdAt and I want to run a query where I can select the employees that were created between 3 to 5 months from **today date**. So if

```
Employee A : 2016 - 01 - 28
Employee B : 2015 -  12 - 14 (less than 3 months from today)
Employee C : 2015 - 9 - 11 (more than 3 months but less than 5 months from today)
Employee D : 2015 - 01 - 20 (more than 5 months from today)
```

then my query should return only   Employee C.

So far I have come up with this.

```
SELECT *
FROM employees
WHERE createdAt > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 Months AND createdAt < NOW() - INTERVAL 5 Months
```

Comment: The compares are wrong. createdAt must greater (>) now - 5 month and createdAt < mow - 3 month.

Comment: `WHERE createdAt > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 Months AND createdAt < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 Months` ... I am giving this for readability @BerndBuffen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start with `lower` date to `higher`. you can try this:

```
  SELECT * FROM employees WHERE date(createdAt) between  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH) and  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```